# python functions for multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, function

below shown the sales data

[image]

i have created function so that i get the summary of sales city wise,

```
import pandas as pd
Super=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Script Testing\supermarket_sales.xlsx")

Location=Super[Super["City"]=="Yangon"]
def Summary():
    PDT=Location.groupby(["Product line","Invoice ID"])["Total"].sum()
    PDTT=PDT.reset_index()
    return PDT
```

can anyone suggest how to run this function across all the cities in the data without creating a separate function for each city

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your own approach, you can add city as a variable to the function and call the function inside a loop:

```
def Summary(city):
    Location=Super[Super["City"] == city]
    PDT=Location.groupby(["Product line","Invoice ID"])["Total"].sum()
    PDTT=PDT.reset_index()
    return PDT

for city in Super['City'].unique():
    PDT = Summary(city)
    #whatever you do with PDT
```